# The JPA doesn't add compound constrait to table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dbeaver

When trying avoid duplicate insert the same value to the combination of two columns ("first_name" and "last_name" for example) i use annotation

```
@Table(name = "author",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"first_name", "last_name"})})
```

as i've read in relevant topic. But it doesn't work. I use JPA Hibernate, DBeaver.

Here's the class.

```
package domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Table(name = "author",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"first_name", "last_name"})})
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "author_id_gen", sequenceName = "author_id", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author_id_gen")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinTable(name = "author_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_fk_id"))
    private List<Address> address;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_id")
    private List<Phone> phones;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_id")
    private List<EMail> eMails;

    public Author(String firstName, String lastName) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = new ArrayList<>();
        this.phones = new ArrayList<>();
        this.eMails = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Author() {
    }

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        this.address.add(address);
    }

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phones.add(phone);
    }

    public void addEMail(EMail eMail) {
        this.eMails.add(eMail);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,

```
@Table(name = "res_location", uniqueConstraints = {
  @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_LOCATION_NAME", columnNames = { "name" }) })
```

Comment: what is your expectation ?. can u share ur script for creating table.?

Comment: u didn't added unique constraint name and share ur script for ref.

Comment: I 've done it before like u'written. It was the same. Sorry, what is script for ref?

Comment: table creation script.

Comment: i dont create table in DB